# Refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git

I have some code in my local directory I don't want to lose. Another dev worked on the code on a remote repo. How can I track my code as old version of the code, and see the difference between my old code and his new code?

I did:

```
git fetch
```

and this worked fine. And now `git pull` gives:

```
$ git pull
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

$ git branch
* master
```

I was getting this log :

[image]

Then I did:

```
$ git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

which probably I shouldn't have done, and now I get this log:

```
*   commit f714790 (HEAD -> master)
|\  Merge: b5b3189 f96113e
| | Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| | Date:   Tue Nov 16 11:10:49 2021 +0100
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/boardlinedevs/boardline-2.1
| | 
| * commit f96113e (origin/master)
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 20:15:35 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Minor
| | 
| * commit 2d653d1
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 20:04:14 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Frequency Center
| | 
| * commit cfd480f
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 19:58:40 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Profile Pages
| | 
| * commit e8163ac
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 19:44:31 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Sorting and order
| | 
| * commit 8725340
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 18:43:07 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Revet
| | 
| * commit 085e4b9
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 18:42:42 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Winning Boards Fixes
| | 
| * commit d0d6d3a
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 16:47:13 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     UI Chnanges 1
| | 
| * commit 2b0599c
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Mon Nov 15 14:21:08 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     Upgrade
| | 
| * commit c30cac4
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Fri Oct 22 13:07:21 2021 +0530
| | 
| |     version 2.1 Patches
| | 
| * commit 8484645
| | Author: remote dev
| | Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:20:12 2020 +0530
| | 
| |     v2.0
| | 
| * commit 7d53386
|   Author: louisrom1 <louisrom1@gmail.com>
|   Date:   Mon Dec 21 20:47:48 2020 +0000
|   
|       Initial commit
| 
* commit b5b3189 (tag: v1.651)
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Sun Jul 13 15:50:04 2014 +0200
| 
|     signin-page on iOS
| 
* commit 5259900
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Wed Mar 5 13:56:50 2014 +0100
| 
|     avant google+ api
| 
* commit aff9516
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Wed Sep 25 12:21:23 2013 +0200
| 
|     modif texte explanation Tom
| 
* commit d399a63
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Mon Jun 10 10:05:42 2013 +0200
| 
|     contact panel with mailto
| 
* commit b980cfa
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Tue Jun 4 15:05:04 2013 +0200
| 
|     big bottom button
| 
* commit f0265d4
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Tue Jun 4 14:58:11 2013 +0200
| 
|     lots of shit
| 
* commit 2aa8b13
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Tue Jun 4 14:57:53 2013 +0200
| 
|     lots of sit
| 
* commit 7bc60eb
| Author: Louisro <louisromain@yahoo.fr>
| Date:   Thu May 23 13:32:00 2013 +0200
| 
|     splash and explanation slideshow
| 
* commit 62fca4d
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Thu Apr 18 10:43:12 2013 +0200
| 
|     version avec jsShare
| 
* commit e329cfe
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Thu Apr 18 00:21:15 2013 +0200
| 
|     disable enable select is ok
| 
* commit 1d41085
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Wed Apr 17 09:54:32 2013 +0200
| 
|     version 3 boutons
| 
* commit a49d512
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Mon Apr 15 17:27:53 2013 +0200
| 
|     avant 3 boutons
| 
* commit fd2c62b
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Tue Apr 9 22:19:27 2013 +0200
| 
|     auto id ok
| 
* commit 68e111b
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Tue Apr 9 22:04:04 2013 +0200
| 
|     before auto id
| 
* commit 4c4b133
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Sun Apr 7 21:45:40 2013 +0200
| 
|     updated db
| 
* commit 3bdcbbe
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Sun Apr 7 00:08:08 2013 +0200
| 
|     file read
| 
* commit 02f8a26
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Fri Apr 5 21:33:16 2013 +0200
| 
|     compute diplay image ok
| 
* commit 2e065b6
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Fri Apr 5 09:41:37 2013 +0200
| 
|     file read
| 
* commit 567136c (tag: 0.9.2beta)
| Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
| Date:   Thu Apr 4 15:17:09 2013 +0200
| 
|     single page
| 
* commit 5926693 (tag: 0.9.1beta)
  Author: louisro <louisro@louisro-ThinkPad-T400.(none)>
  Date:   Thu Apr 4 14:06:26 2013 +0200
  
      multi page
```

Whereas I would like all commits to be on the same line (same branch).

How can I clean this mess?

### Edit

I managed to go back before the unfortunate git pull using

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

But now I still have to connect the local and remote branch, the idea is not to loose my local work and to be able to diff the changes made by the remote dev.

### Edit 2

Now I have:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 20 and 11 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../.htaccess
    ../.htaccessbackup
    ../.htpasswd
    ../.~lock.accord de confidentialite.docx#
    ../13_02_2014_CDL_Introduction_Pitch.pdf
    ../BLPictoRapport.pdf
    ../BLtextonlyproof.txt
    ../BLtextonlyproofedbytTom.txt
    ../BOARDLINE presentation.pdf
    ../BoardLine.docx
    ../BoardLine.ipa
    ../Boardline input Sylvain.wav
    ../ESI_STOCK BOARD CATALOGUE 2013.xls
    ../FRANCE Shapers Tour.pdf
    ../Feedback_Ionic.pptx
    ../FlexSlider-7ecc526/
    ../GoogleService-Info.plist
    ../JQM_version/
    ../Ja.txt
    ../OpenFB-master/
    ../PR_BoardLine_NewBrands_Jan2015.doc
    ../Plan.xlsx
    ../Screens for developper ANUJ/
    ../ScreenshotBureauPhilippe.doc
    ../ScreenshotOrdiLouisRo.png
    ../Strategie.xlsx
```

Answer (score 2):

To get what you have asked for, you need to:

1. reset away the merge (which you already did), then
2. rebase or cherry-pick your original commits atop his commits, so that you add your commits to the history that consists of his commits.

You may (or may not) have some merge conflicts to deal with in step 2.

To do this with rebase, consider a simple:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

(though now that [you have reset your own commits away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69987671/1256452), you will have to reset to put them back, using the reflogs or the raw hash IDs from your question, e.g., `git reset --hard b5b3189`).

Answer (score 1):

ok it seems that

```
$ git stash; git fetch origin; git reset --hard origin/master
```

did the job

Comment: Your `git reset --hard` discarded your own history, and used his history instead. (Remember that in Git, "history" = "commits". You've thrown away your commits in favor of his. If that's what you wanted to do, you're all set.)